# Is this C pattern only used for hiding implementation details?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

This may be basic for the C aficionados but I have a question or two about the following pattern I've seen in some C projects:

SomeType.h:

```
typedef struct SomeType *SomeTypeRef;
```

SomeType.m:

```
struct SomeType
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

main.m

```
#import "SomeType.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // What can i do with you?
    SomeTypeRef myTypeRef;
    return 0;
}
```

So from what I can tell, other parts of the program (like main here) can only pass around SomeTypeRef's, and are not actually able to use the SomeType struct, yes?

Just from experimenting a bit, there appears to be no way to deference myTypeRef in main.  This makes sense because the definition of that struct is "hidden".  Is my understanding correct here?

Finally, why is the compiler happy when it sees the typedef in SomeType.h? It doesn't know anything about the struct it is typedef'ing to, but I guess that is just not important?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  You can swap around the implementation without introducing breaking changes.  Be careful with this though; only do it when necessary.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer

Comment: Thanks for the wiki link; that pretty much explains it.  Why be careful with this though? What are the pitfalls?

Comment: Because hiding pointer types makes your code harder to use/understand in many cases.  I like Linus' take on it: http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0206.1/0402.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information hiding isn't sufficient reason to typedef to a pointer, as you could simply use struct SomeType* directly in main with exactly the same effect.

A better reason to do this kind of typedef to a pointer is to hide the fact that it is in fact a pointer.  This gives you the option, later on, to change the Ref type to be a less direct reference for the purpose of moving allocated memory chunks around for more efficient memory usage.  This was an important thing to do in older versions of Windows, for example.

Most modern operating systems use virtual memory to hide this sort complexity though, making such a typedef mostly a relic from the past.

Answer (score 1):

Yes darren!You are absolutely right.

Firstly , SomeTyperRef's can't be changed form a function (like main) ,because you have declared it in SomeType.h fie.

Secondly,your understanting is correct.

There is a more "elegant" way to hide information ,using opaque pointers , but you have to be extremely careful ! You can see a great example at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553750/what-is-an-opaque-pointer-in-c) !