# How can I share an array between the C files of a library, without the array being visible to the outside?

Tags: c, arrays

### Context

I am in the process of writing a small library in C for an embedded system. The library is at the moment fairly small, but I would like to implement a nice structure for the library from the beginning on. At the moment i have split the implementations of the prototypes into several c files, but I only have one header file.

### Problem

In this library I need a number of arrays of structs that are visible to the different c files of the library, but invisible to the user of the library.
How can I share an array between the C files of a library, without the array being visible to the outside?

Comment: I think you might be looking for opaque pointers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553750/what-is-an-opaque-pointer-in-c#answer-7553775

Comment: What sort of library?