# Why AVIOContext named pb in AVFormatContext

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm reading ffmpeg code and confused by "AVIOContext *pb". Most of the fields' name is straightforward such as "priv_data" means private data, but I don't know why the "AVIOContext" field named "pb".

Comment: That label has been present from the start - my guess is **p**acket **b**uffer since I/O ops are typically buffered.

Comment: thanks @Gyan. packet buffer is good, and I have another guess: **P**ointer to **B**ytestream IO Context

Answer (score 0):

Both `packet buffer` or `Pointer to Bytestream IO Context` can explain the meaning of this name.

---

This is a compilation of the comments by [Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420903/why-aviocontext-named-pb-in-avformatcontext/78025687#comment99453775_56420903) and [jasonxia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420903/why-aviocontext-named-pb-in-avformatcontext/78025687#comment99637567_56420903).

Answer (score -1):

Plus what Gyan says, I believe it is also about **opaqueness**. Check this for more info:[What is an opaque pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553750/what-is-an-opaque-pointer-in-c)

Comment: Opaque pointers have nothing to do with the name, which is what @jasonxia is asking about.

Comment: This is not C question, this is ffmpeg question. I bet you never used libav and thus AVIOContext. When FFmpeg developers choose this kind of names (pb), IT IS about "information hiding". So does my answer.