# What is the use of stat.h in cat.c file of the xv6 os?

Tags: c, xv6

What is the use of the `stat.h` header in `cat.c`?

Here you have the `cat.c`

https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/user/cat.c

Here you have the `stat.h`

https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/kernel/stat.h

I do not see any direct use of the `stat` struct in the `cat.c` so I wonder if there is an indirect one.

Comment: https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/commit/8b58e81077abf4e843873f16c03077e2fafce52d

Comment: @kirjosieppo If you see the answer in the commit, please write an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was added in [this commit](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/commit/8b58e81077abf4e843873f16c03077e2fafce52d) probably because [user.h](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/8b58e81077abf4e843873f16c03077e2fafce52d/user.h#L16) uses the `struct stat *` datatype

Comment: Thanks, I'm learning c along xv6 .... so probably this is more a c question then xv6 .. but why the include statement is then not in the user.h file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7553750/17635987 is perhaps relevant here.

Comment: I see, that' way people can define their stat without need to change user.h... the downside is that you need to bring it around stat.h with user.h even when as in this case you do not need the fstat which is where stat.h is needed.