# How to use OpenSSL connection struct as an object, not pointer

Tags: c++, openssl

At the moment I have something resembling this:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

class Connectivity
{
    Connectivity()
    {
        // Connect etc
        ssl_connection = SSL_new(_ssl_context);
    }

    SSL_CTX* _ssl_context;
    SSL* _ssl;
};
```

However, I'd like to change `_ssl` and `_ssl_context` from pointers, to objects. However, I get this compiler error:

```
error: field ‘_ssl’ has incomplete type ‘SSL’ {aka ‘ssl_st’}
```

Is it possible to declare them as objects?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are [defined](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/b85d53c1670e47273827bba508daff310c3263ab/include/openssl/types.h#L187) as [opaque types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553750/what-is-an-opaque-pointer-in-c). So, they can update library implementation (fix vulnerabilities) without requiring to re-compile applications.