# Why are zeros being added in between valid results of Matrix addition in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently building a Matrix calculator to add matrices, and for some reason when I add two matrices together, the correct answers for each point in matrix addition get spaced out, and in between them are zeros.

For example,

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
+
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

results in

```
2 0 2
0 2 0
2 0 2
```

instead of a matrix full of twos .

here is the code for the printing and adding function for the matrices

```
void printMatrix(int matriks,int matrix[3][3]) {

    int row;
    int column;

    printf("matriks %d:\n",matriks);
    for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
            printf(" %d", matrix[row][column]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }


}

void addMatrices(int m1[3][3], int m2[3][3], int *result[3][3])  {

   int row;
   int col;
    for (row=0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (col=0; col<3;col++) {
            result[row][col] = m1[row][col] + m2[row][col];
        }
    }


}
```

and this is how theyre called in main()

```
 int result[3][3];
 int sampleM1[3][3] = {{1,1,1}, {1,1,1}, {1,1,1}};
 int sampleM2[3][3] = {{1,1,1}, {1,1,1}, {1,1,1}};
 addMatrices(sampleM1,sampleM2,&result);
 printMatrix(0,result);
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Pay attention to the warnings from the compiler!

Comment: k12293139, `int *result[3][3]` acts like a 3x3 arrays of pointers.  `&result` result matches `int (*result)[3][3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't treat `result` as a pointer to a two-dimensional array, arrays are, when passed to a function, implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of that array. So you're doing an extra level of indirection above what you need.

In other words, the function declaration should be:

```c
void addMatrices(int m1[3][3], int m2[3][3], int result[3][3]) {
```

and the call should be:

```c
addMatrices(sampleM1,sampleM2,result);
```

---

A decent compiler should have warned you of this:

```
prog.c: In function ‘addMatrices’:
prog.c:21:30: error: assignment to ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
   26 |             result[row][col] = m1[row][col] + m2[row][col];
      |                              ^
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:30:32: error: passing argument 3 of ‘addMatrices’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   37 |  addMatrices(sampleM1,sampleM2,&result);
      |                                ^~~~~~~
      |                                |
      |                                int (*)[3][3]
prog.c:16:51: note: expected ‘int * (*)[3]’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[3][3]’
   20 | void addMatrices(int m1[3][3], int m2[3][3], int *result[3][3])  {
      |                                              ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

And just a bit of advice: once you start creating higher-level data structures, it's best to have them act much the same as C++ classes. In other words, place them into their own header and source files as *specific* types, rather than having to deal with the general types provided by C (like arrays).

For example, have a structure along the lines of:

```c
// Everything you need to know about a matrix (of integers).

typedef struct {
    size_t rows, cols;
    int *data;
} tIntMatrix; // Poor man's template :-)
```

and provide functions to manipulate the specialised types directly:

```c
// Allocate and de-allocate functions.
tIntMatrix *IntMatrixCreate(size_t rows, size_t cols);
tIntMatrix *IntMatrixCreateAndInit(size_t rows, size_t cols, int *values);
void IntMatrixDestroy(tMatrix *matrix);

// Get and set functions.
int IntMatrixGet(size_t row, size_t col);
void IntMatrixSet(size_t row, size_t col, int value);
void IntMatrixSetRow(size_t row, int *values);
void IntMatrixSetCol(size_t col, int *values);
void IntMatrixSetAll(int *values);

// Matrix manipulation functions, whatever is needed.
void IntMatrixAdd(tMatrix *m1, tMatrix *m2, tMatrix *sum);
void IntMatrixMult(tMatrix *m1, tMatrix *m2, tMatrix *product);
void IntMatrixInvert(tMatrix *m1, tMatrix *inversion);

// Traverse cells with a callback function.
// Function receives, for each cell: rows, cells, row, cell, value.
typedef void (*)(size_t, size_t, size_t, size_t, int) IntMatrixCb;
void  IntMatrixProcess(tIntMatrix *matrix, IntMatrixCb callback);
```

C *can* be (at least partially) object-oriented, it just takes a little more work, but doing so provides much the same safety as those languages that are *inherently* object oriented, like encapsulation in this case.

By that, I mean the internal data structure is hidden<sup(a) from you, all you need to know, in order to be able to use the matrices, is the API.

Then, with use of a callback function:

```c
void cbPrint(int size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t row, size_t col, int value) {
    printf("%d", value);
    putchar(col == cols - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
}
```

Your main code then becomes something like:

```c
tIntMatrix *sampleM1 = IntMatrixCreateAndInit(3, 3, {
    1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1
});
tIntMatrix *sampleM2 = IntMatrixCreateAndInit(3, 3, {
    1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1
});
tIntMatrix *result = IntMatrixCreate(3, 3);

IntMatrixAdd(sampleM1, sampleM2, result);

puts("Matriks 0:"); IntMatrixProcess(result, cbPrint);
```

---

<sup(a) Yes, I know you can *see* the `rows/cols/data` structure but you don't have to *use* it if the API is any good. And, you can hide it behind [an opaque pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553750/what-is-an-opaque-pointer-in-c/7553775#7553775) if you *really* want it hidden.

Comment: Thank you! im at an introductory class, so im still a beginner at C, and feel like theres so many things to learn but your answer helped me.

Answer (score 1):

When you're compiling, turn warnings on, e.g. on gcc via `-Wall`.

If you would have done that, you would have seen a bunch of warnings as can be seen here: https://godbolt.org/z/79a7drWar

You should know, that arrays will decay to pointer if passed as argument to a function (see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Array_to_pointer_conversion).

Change

```
void addMatrices(int m1[3][3], int m2[3][3], int *result[3][3]);
```

to

```
void addMatrices(int m1[3][3], int m2[3][3], int result[3][3]);
```

and call it without the address of operator

```
addMatrices(sampleM1,sampleM2,result);
```