# enabling "differing levels of indirection" warning/error in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

We have a handle type declared like:

```
typedef void *config_h;
```

We have a function declared like:

```
void func(config_h hConfig);
```

I called it like this:

```
config_h hConfig;
func(&hConfig);
```

Not even a warning.  Things I cannot change about this project:  It is `C++11`, and compiled with `-fpermissive`.  The `config_h` typedef is done in a file that is also compiled by C compilers, btw..

I looked here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Looked like `-Wstrict-aliasing` might be the ticket, but it was not.  I get loads of warnings about various pointer conversions, but not this one.

The question is "What is the narrowest warning (or preferably error) I can enable to prevent this problem?"

Bonus question:  If stuff like this drives me nuts, is switching to `clang` likely to pay dividends?

Comment: `&hConfig` is a `void**`. Any data pointer, including `void**`, can be converted to `void*`. How should the compiler know that this particular conversion isn't what you wanted?

Comment: `void *` is a generic pointer. Anything can be converted to a `void *`. You're basically getting what you're asking for. This is a typical situation when calling C code is involved. This is why you always write a wrapper for C code that takes fully-typed parameters, and passes them to C code as a generic void pointer, so that the C++ code is sill type-safe. Do whatever you need to do to have a type-safe facade for C code, to avoid this problem.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - This is 200,000 lines of C code written in the 80s, ported to C++ in the early 2000s.  `Wrapping` the Cisms would be....a fruitless endeavor.  That said...`Uintptr_t` or `char*` would be possible....for at least these handles.  And to clarify, I am not calling C code.  The header file is just compiled by multiple compilers.

Comment: One way to do handles is `typedef struct nonexisting_handle_struct_1 *handle1; typedef struct nonexisting_handle_struct_2 *handle2;` etc

Comment: @immibis - thank you...that's a good point...I was just thinking about forward-declaring the backing objects...I might prefer your method since this is in-theory in a "public" header.  I honestly just had no idea how little type-safety `void *` had.  I knew it was basically none, but I thought at least differing levels of indirection could cause an explicit cast to be required....

Comment: I would suggest changing the definition to `typedef char *config_h;`

Comment: The comment of @immibis reminds me to a technique called "opaque structs" (which we especially use for C API bindings of C++ libraries). Googling "C struct opaque", I found e.g. [SO: Opaque C structs: how should they be declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3965279/7478597).

Comment: Looking at results of `Find all "typedef.*void\s*\*.*_h", Regular expressions` and sobbing.

Comment: Oh good...one of the handles is returned interchangeably as two different types through various public functions.  Except the public APIs can't treat them interchangeably.  So much rage....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out to me by several folks in the comments (thanks all), even differing levels of indirection aren't considered when it comes to `void*`.  I verified this in other compilers.  So the answer to my actual question, best I can tell, is that **there is no warning or error that can be enabled, regardless of compiler**.

That said, if the `void*` actually points to a concrete type, it is relatively painless, even in very large solutions to clean this up.  I went with forward-declaring the types:

```
struct config_o;
typedef config_o* config_h;
//removed typedef void* config_h;
```

I was able to clean up about 40 handle types in 200,000 lines of code in significantly less than 8 hours.  Found (and fixed) several serious bugs while I was at it, which consumed the majority of the time.