# Does the ISO 9899 standard has reserved any use of the _t suffix for identifiers?

Tags: c

I can read in many books and an other SO questions that the standard may expand the set of identifiers such as `size_t` or `int32_t`, so it reserves any use of the `_t` suffix for identifiers.

Is that true?

I could not find anything that discourage the use of this suffix in the **ISO9899:1999** standard, but that standard is hard to read :(

Comment: Reading the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent), it seems that it's not reserved in the C standard, but POSIX does reserve it, so any POSIX-compliant code should not use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard C allows you to use the `_t` suffix so long as you don't end up with a token that starts with a double underscore. (Note that C++ restricts this further in that a double underscore is not allowed anywhere in the token; worth adhering to should you anticipate your code reaching C++.)

It's POSIX that reserves `_t`.

Comment: If memory serves double underscores are only reserved at the beginning of an identifier in C. Anywhere else is fair game. It's C++ that restricts it further.

Comment: That's not a bad rule of thumb to go by if working with both

Comment: Also, you could not start an identifier with `_` followed by another `_`  or a capital letter such as `_Afoo`.

Answer (score 15):

No, it's not true.

The standard reserves the right to add identifiers *starting with `int` or `uint`* and ending `_t` to the `stdint.h` header (§7.31.10). Those identifiers are technically only reserved if that header is included but since it almost always is, they should be treated as reserved.

In general, the standard reserves identifiers defined in standard headers, or mentioned in the future directions for standard headers (§7.31). Identifiers having external linkage (library functions) are reserved for that use (which doesn't stop you from using them as local or static variables, for example). If the library header is included, then its identifiers are reserved for use at file scope. Read §7.1.3 for details.

As that section indicates,  the only identifiers unconditionally reserved are those which start with an underscore followed by a capital letter or a second underscore.

While reading the standard, it's important to understand the difference between contexts in which a name is reserved:

- *Reserved for any use* (identifiers starting with an underscore followed by another underscore or a capital letter): these identifiers may be used by the implementation as macros or special symbols which are handled in some idiosyncratic way by the compiler. Do not ever define one of these in your code, and use the ones which are documented only as indicated by the documentation. Do not use such a symbol if it is not documented, even if you see it used in some standard library header. Or someone else's code.
- *Reserved at file scope* (other identifiers starting with an underscore, not part of any standard header): These identifiers will not be used as macros, and you must not define them as macros either. You may use them as local variables, labels, parameters, and `struct` or `union` members. Personally, I wouldn't do this, but it's permitted. I prefer to put an underscore at the *end* of an identifier which is used in some internal context.
- *Reserved at file scope and as a macro name* (any identifier mentioned in an *included* standard header, including in the future directions clause): Again, since these identifiers may be macros, you should treat them as off limits if you `#include` the associated header. The standard does allow you to `#undef` an identifier used as a function name in the standard library, although you might find that performance suffers because the macro wraps a construct with equivalent semantics but optimised performance.
- *Reserved for use as an identifier with external linkage* (any identifier defined in any standard library header as having external linkage, whether or not the header is included, including the identifier `errno`): The weakest reservation. If you don't include the associated header, you're free to use such an identifier, even at file scope, as long as it is not externally visible. So it could be a file-scope `static` or an enumeration member or the tag of a `struct` or `union`. The point of this clause is not to allow you to deliberately shadow the name of a standard library function. Rather, it is to protect you from future additions to the standard library which might export an external symbol you're currently using. Of course, if your current use is as an externally visible identifier, you're still going to have a future problem. But on the whole, externally visible symbols should be prefixed with a package name to avoid name collisions with other libraries.

---

Having said all that, it's unwise to use an identifier that looks like it might be a standard identifier. Posix includes a list of over a hundred patterns for identifier names that it might use in the future, including all identifiers ending `_t`, so if you expect your code to be used in a Posix environment, you'll want to avoid those names. And while future C standard revisions might avoid adding new type names to existing headers (aside from the integer typenames mentioned above), you don't really want to preclude using any such new types, since they may well be useful. (And, according to a comment by @JensGustedt, who knows a lot more about the workings of the C working group than I do, there will be a couple of new type names in existing headers in C2x.)

Comment: Vastly superior detail to my answer, have an upvote, and hopefully the OP will accept this one.

Comment: Almost all correct,  but there is certainly no promise by the C standard here. These are only indications of which identifiers *might* be added in the future. C2x will definitively use identifiers that had not previously been reserved.

Comment: Yes. Eg `math.h` will add things like `cospi`.

Comment: AFAIR there will be `femode_t` in `fenv.h`, and also some `float32_t` and similar in a new appendix adding to `math.h`.

Comment: @jens: Interesting. I thought `float32_t` was going to go into `stdfloat.h`. But I admit I don't try to track C changes as closely as I used to. Anyway, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 9):

The `_t` suffix is not reserved by ISO 9899 as such. The future library directions for C11 revision does only say that ([C11 7.31.10](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.31.10)):

> 1. Typedef names *beginning with* `int` or `uint` and ending with `_t` may be 
>      added to the types defined in the `<stdint.h>` header. [...]

That said, there are great many types with `_t` suffix defined in C11:

> `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `clock_t`, `cnd_t`, `constraint_handler_t`, `div_t`, `double_t`, `errno_t`, `fenv_t`, `fexcept_t`, `float_t`, `fpos_t`, `imaxdiv_t`, 
>   `int_fast`**`N`**`_t`, `int_least`**`N`**`_t`, `intmax_t`, `int`**`N`**`_t`, `intptr_t`, `ldiv_t`, `lldiv_t`, `max_align_t`, `mbstate_t`, `mtx_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `rsize_t`, 
>   `sig_atomic_t`, `size_t`, `thrd_start_t`, `thrd_t`, `time_t`, `tss_dtor_t`, `tss_t`, `uint_fast`**`N`**`_t`, `uint_least`**`N`**`_t`, 
>   `uintmax_t`, `uint`**`N`**`_t`, `uintptr_t`, `wchar_t`, `wctrans_t`, `wctype_t`, `wint_t`

[POSIX, on the other hand, **reserves** the `_t` suffix for system use.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12727104/918959) The POSIX 1003.1 rationale has this excerpt:

> To allow implementors to provide their own types, all conforming applications are required to avoid symbols ending in `_t`, which permits the implementor to provide additional types.

All in all, considering that the chances are that you want to use your C code in a POSIX system now or later, to steer away from using `_t` for your own types.

Comment: Thanks for the list of `_t` types.  Confident it is complete?  I see none missing. Looks good also for C17/18 too. (of course not much changed there.)