# Unsigned user-defined integer literal

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer, user-defined-literals, signed-integer, negative-integer

Suppose I want to define an integer literal which also allows for negative values, e.g. `-12_km`.

I.e., I would like to do

```
using coord_t = long long;
coord_t operator "" _km(long long int);
```

However, this is not accepted by my compiler (gcc).

[The standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) mentions a list of the allowed types for the parameter list of such a literal operator, but no signed integer type is among them.

Why is the standard like that? Why doesn't it allow for user-defined signed integer literals?

Answer (score 3):

Because there are no negative integer literals in the grammar. Let's put aside the user-defined nature of your question. When we write `-12`, it's the literal `12`, which has unary `-` applied to it. The grammatical definition of an integer literal contains no mention of a minus sign.

> [**[lex.icon]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.icon) (redacted and edited)
>
> ```
> integer-literal:
>     decimal-literal integer-suffix
>
> decimal-literal:
>     nonzero-digit
>     decimal-literal digit
>
> nonzero-digit: one of
>     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
>
> digit: one of 
>     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

It's right there in the grammar. There are no productions that produce negative integer literal. And that is why user-defined literals follow the same convention. Their grammar production simply reuses the production for an integer literal

> [**[lex.ext]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.ext)
>
> ```
> user-defined-literal:
>     user-defined-integer-literal
>
> user-defined-integer-literal:
>     decimal-literal ud-suffix
> ```

Since negation is always an expression other than a literal, you need to overload the appropriate operator for `coord_t`. And by the way, the same applies for `+12`. It's a unary plus applied to `12`, not a literal by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Because there are no negative integer literals in C++. `-12` is actually the minus operator applying to the positive literal `12`. That's the very reason why

- [-9'223'372'036'854'775'808LL is unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61290255/995714)
- [we must define `INT_MIN` as `-INT_MAX - 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003893/995714)
- [`-2147483648 > 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14695118/995714) and [`0 < -0x80000000`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34182672/995714) in some compilers

So you need to overload the unary minus operator to use `-12_km`

```
coord_t operator "" _km(unsigned long long);
coord_t operator-();
```

Comment: I've got `using coord_t = long long;` and the compiler gives errors when I try to define the unary minus `operator` in that way. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @TimKuipers why do you overload without declaring a class? `coord_t` needs to be a struct or class. And you should also change the name because names ending with `_t` are reserved in POSIX: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/995714), [Does the ISO 9899 standard has reserved any use of the _t suffix for identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56935852/995714). In fact `coord_t` is also a common name so you'll have a high chance of name clashing

Comment: there's also [Boost.Units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) that you can use if possible to avoid redefining unist yourself

Comment: thanks for the `_t` info. `coord_t` is not a class or struct, it's a typename for the primitive type `long long`.

Comment: In the mean time I've found out that I don't need to overload the unary minus operator at all.

Comment: @TimKuipers it's because your `coord_t` is just an alias of `long long`