# How to name structs and types correctly in C?

Tags: c, naming-conventions

I have tried to find out, how to name a struct and type correctly. I always found what not to do ("__name", "_Name"), so I always did it like this:

```
typedef struct something_t {
    ...
} something_t;
// or
typedef struct something_that_should_not_be_copied_t {
    ...
} something_that_should_not_be_copied_t[1];
```

But I think this is not fully correct, because `_t` is reserved for type names, so "struct something_t" is not allowed. I also heard, that "struct something_s" is correct, but I have never seen it in any code base. So please, tell me, what is the correct way to do this in a normal program and in a library.

Comment: "But I think this is not fully correct, because _t is reserved for type name" - can you provide a reference to the C Standard where there is said that such names are reserved?

Comment: [https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html)

Comment: "`_t` is reserved for type names" : no it's not, it's rather a convention. `typedef struct something {...} something_t;` would be the idiomatic way. BTW the `[1]` is wrong, you probably should not put it there in the first place. Otherwise explain.

Comment: @Tenobaal I have not found in the C Standard that such names like name_t are reserved.

Comment: `something_t` is not reserved by the standard but by POSIX, check [Does the ISO 9899 standard has reserved any use of the _t suffix for identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935852/does-the-iso-9899-standard-has-reserved-any-use-of-the-t-suffix-for-identifiers), on the other hand, the `_s` suffix is commonly used to indicate that it is the "safe" version of `something`, while `_r` stands for "reentrant" version

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you for the answer. So as I understand it is ok to use the `_t` postfix for a struct, is that correct? The `[1]` is so that the value can only be passed by reference but is stack allocated. gmplib makes use of this too.

Comment: _it is ok to use the _t postfix for a struct, is that correct?_ it depends on which headers you `include`, i.e. including  `sys/types.h` and your own `id_t` or `pid_t` or `clock_t` etcetera ... will give you a nice error: `error: conflicting types for ‘pid_t’; /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:97:17: note: previous declaration of ‘pid_t’ with type ‘pid_t’` my advice is to avoid `_t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `typedef struct { } name;`, you don't even need to state a struct tag. This is only required if you are doing something special like a self-referencing struct or an implementation of "opaque types". So the most common solution would simply be to omit the struct tag.

struct tags and `typedef` names exist in different name spaces, so you can name them the same if you fancy, as far as the C language is concerned.

There is as far as I know no convention for naming struct tags. However, some coding standards like the Linux kernel encourages `struct tag` over typedef, for completely subjective reasons.

`_t` at the end of a type *is* a common naming convention for types however. It is fine to use, although prohibited by the POSIX standard.

Depending on what kind of application you are writing, you could either follow things like the Linux kernel coding style or POSIX, or you can completely ignore them.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I'm afraid not very helpful, the problem is usually not related to naming an internal tag for the structure but to the name of the instantiated variables, e.g. `typedef struct { } name;` and then `name name;` is an error, so you have to invent another name for the variables, while `name_t name` is syntactically correct (despite being reserved by POSIX).

Comment: @DavidRanieri Not quite sure how you picked that up between the lines of the question, but I didn't...

Comment: I deduce this from the `naming-conventions` tag ... although I may be wrong

Comment: @DavidRanieri Don't worry, your comment was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My convention is to add the suffix *Desc* (descriptor) for the record type (struct). This convention is used in the Oberon programming language. If the type is a part of a module inteface I also add the module name with an underscore as a prefix. For instance, if I have a module *Stacks* I would declare the stack type in the header file `Stacks.h` as

```
typedef struct Stacks_StackDesc *Stacks_Stack;
```

and define it in the implementation file `Stacks.c` as something like

```
struct Stacks_StackDesc {
    int items[100];
    int count;
};
```

I now have an abstract data type names *Stacks_Stack*.

Adding a module prefix for the type may seem superfluous but it makes the code more consistent if each exported identifier has it. If you search for the string "Stacks_" in a client module you can easily see all identifiers used from module *Stacks*, like *Stacks_Push*, *Stacks_Pop* etc.