# Inheritance and method overriding in C - how to make it defined behaviour

Tags: c, oop, language-lawyer, dynamic-cast, strict-aliasing

I have my custom little OOP-esque inheritance functionality, something like this:

```
// base class
struct BaseTag;

typedef struct {
    int (*DoAwesomeStuff)(struct BaseTag* pInstance);
} S_BaseVtable;

typedef struct BaseTag{
    S_BaseVtable* pVtable;
    int AwesomeValue;
} S_Base;

// child class
struct ChildTag;

typedef struct {
    S_BaseVtable Base;
    void (*SomeOtherStuff)(struct ChildTag* pInstance);
} S_ChildVTable;

typedef struct ChildTag {
    S_Base BaseClass;
    int EvenAwesomerValue;
} S_Child;
```

Now let's say I have a Child class constructor where the Base class vtable is overridden with the child vtable:

```
void Child_ctor(S_Child* pInstance) {
    Base_ctor((S_Base*) pInstance);
    pInstance.BaseClass.pVtable = (S_BaseVtable*) &MyChildVTable;
}
```

Also in this child vtable, I want to override the `DoAwesomeStuff()` method from base class with a method like this:

```
int Child_DoAwesomeStuff(struct BaseTag* pInstance) {
    S_Child* pChild = (S_Child*) pInstance; // undefined behaviour
    return pChild->EvenAwesomerValue;
}
```

I have seen this pattern in variations occasionally, but I see some problems with it. My main questions are

- How can I access the `S_ChildVtable` from a child instance that is hidden behind a `S_BaseVtable` pointer?
- How can I properly cast the `pInstance` argument of `Child_DoAwesomeStuff()` to an `S_Child*` type?

As far as I understand the C standard, casting from `S_Child*` to `S_Base*` (and the corresponding vtable types) is okay as the first member of `S_Child` is an `S_Base` instance. But vice versa it is undefined behaviour.

Would something like `S_Child* pChild = (S_Child*)((char*) pInstance)` be legal and defined?

---

**Edit**

My question was a bit unclear and misleading.
It's not the cast itself that I think is UB, but dereferencing pChild after it was cast from pInstance.

I browsed through the C11 standard again to find some reference but not it's not so clear to me anymore.

6.3.2.3/7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
> resulting pointer is not correctly aligned (68) for the referenced type, the behavior is
> undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
> original pointer.

So I guess my question really is - What mechanics need to be in place so that it is ensured that S_Base and S_Child are correctly aligned?

Comment: *undefined behaviour* says who? What you can cast in one direction, you can cast in the other direction.

Comment: Technically, casting between pointer to any struct is *always* defined. Accessing the struct via a pointer of invalid type can be UB.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant - not the cast, but the access is UB. I clarified this in the question. tsantisl, what exactly qualifies as invalid type as per your comment?

Comment: If you cast something to something else and back again, you get what you have started with. If the pointer was valid at the beginning, it is valid at the end.

Comment: I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75903325/4561887) to more-thoroughly address "undefined behavior", and your new questions you added in your edit.

Comment: `BaseClass` is always correctly aligned as it is a struct member .  In brief you can always cast the address of an `S_Child` object that exists, to `S_Base` and back again.   But if you have some other `S_Base` object that is not actually a subobject of an `S_Child`, then you can't cast that to an `S_Child` and dereference.   Can you clarify whether you are asking about both of those scenarios, or just the first one?

Answer (score 1):

### Undefined behavior: memory usage in C, when it *is* or is *not* undefined behavior

#### 1st, some background study: let us understand what is and is not undefined behavior when managing memory in C

As is frequently the case in programming, there are a lot of *nuances* to discuss. So, let me try to address the edits to your question.

> My question was a bit unclear and misleading. It's not the cast itself that I think is UB, but dereferencing `pChild` after it was cast from `pInstance`.

In C, casting is undefined behavior for a variety of reasons, but not in the casts you are doing in your question. See the comments below this answer for more insight.

*Dereferencing* is undefined behavior for a few reasons as well, including these two main ones I will talk about which may be most relevant to your question:

1. you are dereferencing out-of-bounds memory that is *unowned* by your program/object, or
2. you are reading *uninitialized* memory/values (even if your program *does* properly own that memory)

Consider the following examples:

1. Example 1: pointing to memory our program does *not* own is undefined behavior

   1. Undefined behavior: on any machine

      ```c
      // arbitrarily point to some address in memory, and assume it's an 8-bit
      // unsigned integer
      uint8_t * p = (uint8_t*)0x1234; // undefined behavior if this address is
                                      // outside all memory addresses
                                      // currently owned by your program

      // now dereference this pointer and assign a value to this integer
      *p = 1; // undefined behavior (whether reading OR writing here) because
              // you are accessing memory that your program does not own nor
              // control!
      ```
   2. NOT undefined behavior: on an ATmega328 8-bit microcontroller (ex: Arduino Uno)

      ```c
      uint8_t * p = (uint8_t*)0x23; // not undefined behavior, because this 
                                    // address belongs to a well-defined
                                    // hardware register used by this mcu

      // now dereference this pointer and assign a value to this integer
      *p = 1; // NOT undefined behavior because the ATmega328 datasheet 
              // (https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/40001906C.pdf)
              // indicates on p445 that address 0x23 is the PINB hardware
              // register, which allows you to read from or toggle IO pins.
              // Writing a 1 here actually toggles the output of GPIO pin B0.
      ```

      Note that the proper way to do the above is this (example file: "/Arduino 1.8.13/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/[iom328pb.h](https://github.com/amoehl/uino-atmega328pb/blob/master/src/tools/include/avr/iom328pb.h#L51-L59)"):

      ```c
      #define PINB    (*(volatile uint8_t *)(0x23))
      #define PINB7   7
      #define PINB6   6
      #define PINB5   5
      #define PINB4   4
      #define PINB3   3
      #define PINB2   2
      #define PINB1   1
      #define PINB0   0

      PINB = 1 << PINB0;
      ```
2. Example 2: using memory we don't own, and/or that is uninitialized, is undefined behavior

   1. Undefined behavior: on any machine

      ```c
      uint32_t * pu32 = (uint32_t*)0x1234; // ok
      uint32_t u1;

      u1 = *pu32; // Undefined behavior! Reading memory our program doesn't 
                  // own

      *pu32 = 0;  // Undefined behavior! Writing to memory our program doesn't
                  // own

      pu32 = &u1; // ok: pointing our pointer to valid memory our program owns

      uint32_t u2;
      u2 = u1;    // Undefined behavior! Reading an undefined value from u1.
      *pu32 = u1; // Undefined behavior! Reading an undefined value from u1.

      u1 = *pu32; // Undefined behavior! Our program DOES own this memory 
                  // that pu32 points to now, but the value stored there is
                  // undefined/uninitialized.
      ```
   2. NOT undefined behavior: on any machine

      ```c
      uint32_t * pu32;
      uint32_t u1;
      pu32 = &u1; // ok: our ptr now points to valid memory
      *pu32 = 7;  // set u1 to 7
      u1 = 8;     // set u1 to 8
      uint32_t u2 = u1;     // set u2 to 8
      uint32_t u3 = *pu32;  // set u3 to 8 (since pu32 points to u1)
      ```
3. Example 3: using a memory pool our program *does* own is *not* undefined behavior

   1. NOT undefined behavior: on any machine

      ```c
      uint8_t memory_pool_of_bytes[4]; // ok
      // ok: pointing our uint32_t* pointer to use this memory pool of bytes
      uint32_t * pu32 = (uint32_t *)memory_pool_of_bytes; 

      *pu32 = 1000000; // ok; our program owns this memory!
      ```

#### Now, with the above knowledge learned, let's look back at your question:

> My question was a bit unclear and misleading. It's not the cast itself that I think is UB, but dereferencing `pChild` after it was cast from `pInstance`.

The answer to this is: **"it depends on whether or not you dereferencing *valid* (owned, and already-initialized if reading it) vs *invalid* (not owned, *or* not initialized) memory.**

Consider the following:

```c
// create a base
S_Base base;
Child_DoAwesomeStuff(&base); // Undefined behavior inside this func??? Maybe!

// vs:

// create a child
S_Child child; 
Child_DoAwesomeStuff((S_Base*)&child); // Undefined behavior inside this func??? 
                                       // No! This is fine.
```

Let's go deeper to explore the 1st case where there is *maybe* undefined behavior.

```c
S_Base base;            // ok: statically allocate a chunk of memory large 
                        // enough to hold an `S_Base` type.
S_Base* pBase = &base;  // ok: create a pointer to point to our memory above.
S_Child* pChild = (S_Child*)pBase; // **technically** ok, but a very bad idea 
                                   // because it **could lead to** undefined
                                   // behavior later! `pChild` does NOT point
                                   // to a "valid complete object of the target
                                   // type".
pChild->BaseClass.AwesomeValue = 7; // fine, because this is owned memory!
pChild->EvenAwesomerValue; // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR! This is NOT owned memory! We
                           // just read outside the memory we statically 
                           // allocated in the first line above!
```

So, is *the `(S_Child*)pBase;` cast* undefined behavior? No! But it is *dangerous*! Is accessing owned memory within `pChild` undefined behavior? No! We own it. Our program allocated it. But, is accessing memory *outside* what our program owns (ex: `pChild->EvenAwesomerValue`) undefined behavior? Yes! We do *not* own that memory. It is similar to the many undefined cases I went through above.

C++ has solved the *dangerous* behavior above by having the `dynamic_cast<>()` conversion which will allow casting a parent type to a child type. It will then *dynamically*, at run-time, check to see if the resulting object ["is a valid complete object of the target type"](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/). If it discovers it is *not*, it sets the resulting pointer to `nullptr` to notify you of that. In C, you have to just track these things manually yourself.

### "What mechanics need to be in place so that it is ensured that `S_Base` (parent) and `S_Child` are correctly aligned?"

This one's easy: just put your `S_Base` struct at the *very beginning* of your `S_Child` struct and they are automatically aligned. Now, a pointer to your `S_Child` object points to the *exact same address* as a pointer to the `S_Base` object within it, since the child *contains* the base object.

They are automatically aligned so long as you don't use any alignment or padding keywords or compiler extensions to change things. Padding is automatically added by the compiler *after* struct members, as needed, never before the first member. See more on that here: [Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4306186/4561887).

Simple example (with*out* any virtual table polymorphism function stuff):

```c
typedef struct parent_s
{
    int i;
    float f;
} parent_t;

typedef struct child_s 
{
    parent_t parent; // parent (base) member MUST be 1st within the child
                     // to be properly aligned with the start of the child!
    int i;
    float f;
} child_t;

child_t child;
parent_t parent;

parent_t* p_parent = &child; // ok; p_parent IS a "valid complete object of the
                             // target [parent] type", since the child's
                             // allocated memory blob does indeed encompass the
                             // parent's
child_t* p_child = &child; // ok; p_child is a "valid complete object of 
                           // the target [child] type"
child_t* p_child = (child_t*)&parent; // DANGEROUS! Technically this cast is 
                                      // *not* undefined behavior *yet*, but it
                                      // could lead to it if you try to access
                                      // child members outside the memory blob 
                                      // created for the parent. 
                                      // 
                                      // p_child is NOT a "valid complete object
                                      // of the target [child] type".
```

For the last (dangerous) cast above, C++ would allow you to have a dynamic cast which would fail at runtime if and only if you called it with C++ dynamic_cast syntax, *and* checked for errors, like this:

```cpp
child_t* p_child = dynamic_cast<child_t*>(&parent);
if (p_child == nullptr)
{
    printf("Error: dynamic cast failed. p_child is NOT a \"valid complete "
           "object of the target [child_t] type.\"");
    // do error handling here
}
```

**Key takeaway:**

Once you first get alignment by putting the parent right at the beginning inside the child, basically just think of each object as a memory blob, or memory pool. If the memory pool you have (are pointing to) is *larger than* the expected size based on the pointer type pointing to it, you're fine! Your program owns that memory. But, if the memory pool you have (are pointing to) is *smaller than* the expected size based on the pointer type pointint to it, you're not fine! Accessing memory outside your allocated memory blob is *undefined behavior*.

In the case of OOP and parent/child relationships, the child object must always be larger than the parent object because *it contains* a parent object within it. So, casting a child to a parent type is fine, since the child type is larger than the parent type and the child type holds the parent type *first* in its memory, but casting a parent type to a child type is *not* fine unless the memory blob being pointed to was created initially as a child of that child type.

Now, let's look at this in C++ and compare to your C example.

### Inheritance and parent <--> child type casting in C++ and C

So long as the `pInstance` pointer being passed to `Child_DoAwesomeStuff()` was actually constructed initially as an `S_Child` object, then casting the pointer back to an `S_Child` pointer (`S_Child*`) is *not* undefined behavior. It would only be undefined behavior if you attempt to cast a pointer to an object that was constructed originally as a `struct BaseTag` (aka `S_Base`) type to a child pointer type.

This is how C++ works too, with `dynamic_cast<>()` (which I mention [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75838664/4561887)).

Example C++ code from https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ under the "dynamic_cast" section is below.

In the C++ code below, notice that both `pba` *and* `pbb` are pointers to the base type (`Base *`), yet, `pba` is actually *constructed* as a `Derived` (child) type via `new Derived`, whereas `pbb` is actually *constructed* as a `Base` (base, or parent) type via `new Base`.

Therefore, casting *`pba`* to `Derived*` is perfectly valid, since it truly is that type, but casting *`pbb`* to `Derived*` is *not* valid, since it is *not* truly that type. C++'s `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pbb)` call catches this undefined behavior at run-time, detecting that the returned type is not a fully-formed `Derived` type, and returns a `nullptr`, which is equal to `0`, so you get the print that says `Null pointer on second type-cast.`

Here is that C++ code:

```cpp
// dynamic_cast
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class Base { virtual void dummy() {} };
class Derived: public Base { int a; };

int main () {
  try {
    Base * pba = new Derived;
    Base * pbb = new Base;
    Derived * pd;

    pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pba);
    if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on first type-cast.\n";

    pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pbb);
    if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on second type-cast.\n";

  } catch (exception& e) {cout << "Exception: " << e.what();}
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Null pointer on second type-cast.
```

Similarly, your C code has the same behavior.

Doing this is valid:

```c
// create a child
S_Child child; 
// treat it like a base (ok since `S_Base` is at the beginning of it--since the
// child contains a base object)
S_Base* pBase = (S_Base*)&child;
// Now obtain the child back from the base pointer
S_Child* pChild = (S_Child*)pBase; // ok, since pBase really points to a 
                                   // child object
```

But doing this is *not* ok:

```c
// create a base
S_Base base;
// Get a pointer to it
S_Base* pBase = &base;
// Now try to magically obtain a child from a base object
S_Child* pChild = (S_Child*)pBase; // NOT ok! **May lead to** undefined behavior 
                                   // when dereferencing, since pBase really
                                   // points to a base object!
```

So, for your specific function:

```c
// Note: I replaced `struct BaseTag*` with `S_Base*` for readability
int Child_DoAwesomeStuff(S_Base* pInstance) {
    S_Child* pChild = (S_Child*) pInstance;
    return pChild->EvenAwesomerValue;
}
```

This is fine:

```c
// create a child
S_Child child; 

Child_DoAwesomeStuff((S_Base*)&child); // ok
```

But this is *not*!:

```c
// create a base
S_Base base;

Child_DoAwesomeStuff(&base); // NOT ok! **May lead to** undefined behavior 
                             // inside this func!
```

### My thoughts on enforcing OoP (Object Oriented Programming) and inheritance in C

Just a warning though: passing around pointers and storing pointers to vtables and functions and things inside C structs will make tracing your code and trying to understand it *very* difficult! No indexer that I am aware of (Eclipse included, and Eclipse has the best indexer I've ever seen), can trace back to which function or type was assigned to a pointer in your code. Unless you're doing this stuff just for a learning exercise, or to bootstrap your own C++ language from scratch in C (again, for learning), I recommend against these patterns.

If you want "object-*oriented*" C with inheritance and all, don't do it. If you want "object-*based*" C, via opaque pointers/structs for basic private-member encapsulation and data hiding, that's just fine! Here's how I prefer to do that: [Option 1.5 ("Object-based" C Architecture)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54488289/4561887).

Last note: you probably know more about virtual tables (vtables) than I do. At the end of the day, it's your code, so do whichever architecture you want, but I don't want to be working in that code base :).

### See also

1. https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ - **excellent** article on typecasting! See in particular the "dynamic_cast" section, and the code snippet therein.
2. [Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4306186/4561887)
3. [my answer] [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast, and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75838664/4561887)
4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: Is there any semantic difference between `(S_Base*)&child)` and `&child.BaseClass`?

Comment: @tstanisl, no, they are the same. This is similar to when you have `int int_array[5]`, you can get a pointer to the first int in the array either by using `int_array` directly, which decays (adjusts) to an `int*`, or you can explicitly get the same thing with `&int_array[0]`. So, even though `(S_Base*)&child)` and `&child.BaseClass` give you the same exact pointer (address) as an `S_Base*` type, I consider `(S_Base*)&child)` to be clearer because it implies that object-oriented inheritance is going on here where a child instance _is a_ base instance as well.

Comment: @tstanisl, side note if interested: I talk more about array-to-pointer decay/adjustment in my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67814330/4561887) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51527502/4561887).

Comment: I generally consider casting an inferior method because it bypasses the type checking that the compiler can offer for free. That is why I prefer "`&parent.base`" when doing OOP in C. I don't see much gains from better expressing the intentions in a form of casting because C focuses on implementation rather than abstractions.

Comment: @tstanisl, that's a very valid argument. I might be persuaded to do your approach there. Perhaps to get the best of both worlds, I'd use a macro to obtain the clarity I want while using your approach to get the automatic type-checking which is better than casting. If I am consistent in *always* calling my base class member `BaseClass`, then I could do that with this: `#define GET_PTR_TO_BASECLASS(child) (&child.BaseClass)`. Then, I'd use it like this: `Child_DoAwesomeStuff(GET_PTR_TO_BASECLASS(child));`. Yes, I like that. Then we get the best of both worlds.

Comment: In your initial explanation, you're missing the MAIN source of undefined behavior when dereferencing a cast pointer -- strict aliasing violations.  If the type by which memory is read through a pointer does not match the type by which that memory was written, you have potential aliasing issues.  There are a number of specific cases where it is ok (one of which being the cast between a struct and its first member), but otherwise it causes undefined behavior which is tough to diagnose as it will usually work fine and only screw up when other apparently unrelated code changes, due to optimization

Comment: In the first example `uint8_t * p = (uint8_t*)0x1234;` is undefined behaviour unless 0x1234 is actually the address of (or within) an object that exists.  You seem to contradict yourself: the text before that code block correctly says "pointing to memory our program does not own is undefined behavior", but then the code comment says "not undefined behaviour"

Comment: "casting is never undefined behavior" is simply false , there are many cases of casts being UB (for integers, floats and pointers) . For pointers, cast with incorrect alignment is UB (not an issue for uint8_t though), and using a cast to produce a pointer that doesn't point to any object is UB

Comment: ... not to mention that any cast between pairs of types for which no conversion is defined has UB.  Examples: Object pointers to and from function pointers.  Any kind of pointer to or from a floating-point type.  Any cast involving a function type (not function pointer).

Comment: @M.M: Implementations that are designed to be suitable for low-level programming on platforms that document a "natural" relationship between integers and addresses will process a construct like `*(unsigned char volatile*)0xC0E9 = 1;` in "a documented manner characteristic of the environment" (e.g. turning on an Apple II's floppy drive motor).  The Standard does not recognize any implementations as being more or less suitable for such purposes than any others, and would allow implementations to process such a construct in any other manner if they thought doing so would be more useful...

Comment: ...or if they felt like making programmers jump through hoops to accomplish things that should be easy.  Since the Standard waives jurisdiction over many constructs that are non-portable but would be correct on the implementations for which they were written, the fact that the Standard waives jurisdiction over a construct in no way implies any judgment that failure to process an action "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment" would not render an implementation unsuitable for many purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> So I guess my question really is - What mechanics need to be in place so that it is ensured that S_Base and S_Child are correctly aligned?

**TL;DR:** no special mechanics are required to cover conversions between pointers to those types that are valid in your inheritance framework.

---

Alignment is described in C17 6.2.8, "Alignment of objects", and touched on in many other places in the spec.

Although the language spec does not explicitly speak to the question, we can observe that the alignment requirement of a structure type must be at least as strict as that of its most strictly-aligned member, else the implementation cannot ensure that all members of all instances will be correctly aligned.  Because your `S_Child` has a member of type `S_Base`, the former cannot have a weaker alignment requirement than the latter, so conversion of a valid `S_Child *` to type `S_Base *` can never run afoul of incorrect alignment.

It is possible for `S_Child` to have a stricter alignment requirement than `S_Base` does, but this is not an issue you need to worry about in practice.  The only case for conversion of an `S_Base *` to type `S_Child *` that is semantically valid in your inheritance system is when the original `S_Base *` points to the first member of an `S_Child`.  In that case, you can rely on the fact that

> A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in
> which it resides), and vice versa.

(C17 6.7.2.1/15)

Of course, this applies in both directions, so it provides additional (even better) support for the `S_Child *` to `S_Base *` case.

Pretty much the same thing applies on the side of your vtables, since you are structuring them analogously to the data-member structures.

> Would something like `S_Child* pChild = (S_Child*)((char*) pInstance)` be legal and defined?

The cast to `char *` is valid if `pInstance` is a valid pointer to any object type, but it does not gain you anything with respect to the conversion of the result to type `S_Child *`.  You might as well just write

```
S_Child *pChild = (S_Child *) pInstance;
```

, which is perfectly fine in all the cases you (should) care about.

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard treats support for many "inheritance-style" idioms as a quality-of-implementation issue.  Implementations which are intended solely for tasks which would not involve such inheritance need not support it, but all or nearly all implementations can be configured to support such constructs.  In clang and gcc, they may be supported by using the `-fno-strict-aliasing` compilation option.

Note that under C89, the idiomatic way of allowing structures to be used interchangeably was to have them start with a common initial sequence.  While some people may argue that C99 was intended to break code using this idiom, that would imply that C99 was written in gross violation of the Committee's charter.  If the authors of C99 were intending to uphold their charter, they would have intended that programs that would benefit from the CIS guarantees would be processed in a manner that supports it, and implementations that don't support it would only be used for tasks that wouldn't benefit from it.

Using the Common Initial Sequence approach, derived structures would start with the same members as their parent structures.  If a structure type and all structures that are derived from it all start with a member having the same name and a distinctive type, then functions which would expect a pointer to a type compatible with the structure type could pass it with a consistent syntax e.g. `&foo->header`.  It may be useful to have macros which would syntactically accept a pointer to any struct following the pattern and wrap it to call an actual function e.g.

```
struct woozle { struct woozleHeader *woozle_hdr; int x, y; };
struct derived_woozle { struct woozleHeader *woozle_hdr; int x, y; double z; };
int do_use_woozle(struct woozleheader **p, int x, int y);
#define use_woozle(it, x, y) do_woozle(&(it)->woozle_hdr, (x), (y))
```

Using macros in this way is a bit ugly, but it will allow code to say `use_woozle(ptr, x, y);` when `ptr` is a pointer to any object which is derived from `woozle` and follows the pattern, while rejecting attempts to pass other things.  By contrast, using a `void*` arguments or casting arguments to a `struct woozle` would bypass type checking that would otherwise usefully catch many mistakes, such as passing pointers with the wrong level of indirection.