# Why does libcap use obfuscated pointer for cap_t

Tags: c, glibc

Why is `cap_t` defined as `_cap_struct *`? What was the reasoning for obfuscating the pointer type and having libcap functions take/return `cap_t` when normal libc usage suggests they would take/return a explicit pointer type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obfuscated pointers (actually *"opaque"*) are used to force applications to use the documented functions for a library rather than bypass those functions and manipulate its data directly.

Doing that lets the developers (of the library) concentrate on making the functions work rather than being distracted by handling data inconsistencies.

Further reading:

- [What is an opaque value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854113/what-is-an-opaque-value)
- [Opaque C structs: how should they be declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965279/opaque-c-structs-how-should-they-be-declared)
- [Why use an opaque “handle” that requires casting in a public API rather than a typesafe struct pointer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294761/why-use-an-opaque-handle-that-requires-casting-in-a-public-api-rather-than-a-t)

Comment: If I may please clarify the question. The question is why has the pointer been rolled into the typedef? I believe you have answered the question, why use a typedef to create an opaque data type.  Thank you.

Comment: @Tobin Because then you don't need to care that it's a pointer. (And maybe in a later version it won't be a pointer, but probably not)

Comment: Thomas Dickey, you are exactly correct, thank you. It seems the confusion was my own. Well done stackoverflow, 4 upvotes on the answer convinced me that the answer was correct and coerced me to understand the problem more thoroughly until I understood the answer. Thanks again.