# Is there another reason for using tags in typedef except for self referencing?

Tags: c++, c, typedef

If I want to create a new struct type that contains a pointer the type itself I wouldn't be able to do

```
typedef struct {
  my_type* p;
} my_type;
```

and I will need to use a tag

```
typedef struct my_tag {
  struct my_tag* p;
} my_type;
```

Is there another use for the tag mechanism? because I've seen it several times and I don't understand why someone would add this to a `typedef`

Also, since C and C++ are a bit different with their `struct` keyword, would that change anything if I typedef such a struct in C or in C++?

Comment: In C `my_tag` is a tag, not a type. `struct my_tag` is a type. In C++ both are types by the former can be hidden by other identifiers without errors. This is a topic where C and C++ really differ, you can read more [here](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4024450/Tag-vs-Type-Names).

Comment: Declaring opaque types?

Comment: You can't forward declare an anonymous struct.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense for C++, I'd suggest removing that tag (har har) completely.

Comment: Note that `typedef`s serve little, if any, fundamental purpose.  They provide a shorthand for expressing type names, and they are a bit of a convenience in certain other, minor ways, but there is nothing you can do with typedefs that you cannot also do without.  Struct (and union) tags are more fundamental.  They are the essential mechanism for reusing a struct definition that appears elsewhere -- either earlier or later in the same translation unit, or even (only) in an entirely different translation unit.  You don't have to typedef a struct type in C.

Comment: 1.  There is no need to make the tag and typedef name distinct in C.  In my view it is better to make them the same (why have two names for the same thing).  2.  There is no need to play this silly game with typedefs in C++ *at all*.  Just write `struct my_type` and be done with it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger agreed. but if I did decide to typedef, I didn't see the point of a tag, and that's why I asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another use is ["opaque type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854113/what-is-an-opaque-value), which is usually forward- declared as

```
typedef struct my_type my_type;
```

where you want to define a type at the same time as you do a forward declaration. `typedef struct my_type;` would have been nonsense. In general, you can't forward-declare without a struct tag.

Answer (score 1):

I looked over the comments and answer, but never saw this.  It seems too obvious for someone to not have already brought it up, so I apologize if this duplicates a response.

In C++, you don't use `typedef struct`.  Instead, add a forward declaration of the incomplete type to the member's declaration:

```
#include <iostream>

struct my_type {
    int i;
    struct my_type* p;
};

int main() {
    my_type my_obj;
    my_obj.i = 100;
    my_obj.p = &my_obj;
    std::cout << my_obj.p->i << '\n';
}
```